# Count Number of results with Limit

Tags: php, mysqli

How do I count number of results with limits? Obviously the code I have is not correct. Any help?

```
$result = mysqli_query ($conn, "select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from $sql $limit");
$db_count = mysqli_query ("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");
```

ANSWER: `$sql = "$db_name.$db_table $where $where_search $db_sort";
$result = mysqli_query ($conn, "select * from $sql $limit");
        $rec = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) as totalCount FROM $sql"));
        $db_count = $rec['totalCount'];`

Comment: What is in `$sql` and `$limit`? What exactly you want to achieve because usin `LIMIT` you will not limit the count but only the returned rows.

Comment: Are you asking for SQL syntax or PHP syntax?

Comment: Could you add your answer as a new answer to your question and mark it as solution? Otherwise this question will remain open even if you found a solution to it. Thanks!